# create query that uses IN returning wrong values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The query

```
select * from PositionTable where Position in (51000785,52012986)
```

returns two records where the position column is '51000785' in the first record and '52012986' in the second.

Using C# I want to return the same results..I have tried

```
string allPositions = "51000785,52012986";
List<PositionTable> Position = new List<PositionTable>();
Position = DbContext.PositionTableList
                           .Where<PositionTable>(p => p.Position == allPositions)
                           .ToList();
```

This result returns nothing, so how can I change the ==allPositions to 'in (allPositions)' is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
        var allPositions = new string[] { "51000785", "52012986" };
        var x = from p in DbContext.PositionTableList
            where allPositions.Contains(p.Position)
            select p;
```